# Is "under tension" a widely enough understood phrase to explain the presence of electric current?

Tags: phrase-usage

I'm trying to write an operations manual for a machine and use the best phrase to explain that certain parts are "live" ie carrying electric current.

If I say "Check that the machine is not under tension", is that completely clear to all ?

Do I need to add the qualifier "not under electrical tension" ?

Is there a better phrase  ?  not live, not under current, etc

Comment: Your suggestion of “under tension” is very technical and unlikely to be widely understood. What about “...the machine is not (still) connected to the electricity supply”? Plain English is very important in all instructions, particularly safety instructions.

Comment: I agree about the importance of safety and plain English, but it is for industrial machinery as opposed to household appliances. I'm trying to get a balance between clear instructions and over-simplified/patronising, but yes maybe "not connected to the electrical supply" does that.  A slight further complication, I think some components may still carry a charge for a while after the supply is disconnected.

Comment: Okay. I was thinking of “not plugged in” too, but that indeed may cross the line and be perceived as talking down to the workers/technicians doing the installation!

Comment: Instead of a "not" phrase, I would write something like: "Ensure that the machine is disconnected from the power supply."

Comment: You are right that "some components may still carry a charge for a while after the supply is disconnected", possibly for *years* in the case of a capacitor. So perhaps additionally "Never touch any electrical components even when there is no power connected."

Comment: As a structural engineer, the phrase "under tension" means something very definite to me, and it's not related to electricity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is potentially a massive liability issue and seems to be an overtly commercial endeavor. The people who write this stuff for a living are well paid  and have billion dollar legal fund war chests. There are countless layers of regulations and tons of legal cases that govern the preparation of these manuals.

Comment: I'm an electrical engineer, and I wouldn't consider it to be idiomatic.

Comment: Simply put, no, it won't be clear. I suspect the vast majority of people will interpret under tension to mean stretched tight, which makes little sense in this context. There are probably many other manuals you can copy from, available online.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that

> Check that the machine is not live

is clear.

The Longman dictionary has the following [definition of live in this context](https://www.ldoceonline.com/Electrical-topic/live):

> a wire or piece of equipment that is live has electricity flowing through it

From the comments, it is not sufficient just to say that it is unplugged or not connected to power. One has to be clear that it must be discharged.

Comment: Gas equipment like fires and cookers are also described as 'live' when they are connected to a gas supply. In fact the supply pipes are also called 'live' when they are connected to mains.